# How to get an xml element response based on recent date in groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to get value of the specific element in response based on updateDate.

I have xml response as below with multiple data returned, i am trying to get say test1 value for the current date or most recent date.I tried getting current date and then comparing the date value and getting the corresponding test1number but it did not work.Can anyone did this before either as part of assertion or through groovy script, thanks.

```
<Tests>
<test1> some value </test2>
<Date> mm/dd/yyyy </Date>
</Tests>

<Tests>
...
...
</Tests>
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: May be you can show your sample input and output data

Answer (score 0):

You should really put some examples of things you tried or more in-depth explanation of what you want to do at the end of the day.

Using xpath you can do this.

Written in a script assertion on a REST request

```
def xmlParser = new XmlSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)
def wantedValue = xmlParser.find{ it.Date.text() == "05/02/2017"}.test1.text()
```

Will return the test1 value where the date equals whatever date you put in there.